# Python Pandas API for Yahoo finance - how to get the bid ask prices and other fields

Tags: python, api, pandas, yahoo, finance

I want to get the bid and ask price of a stock on Yahoo Finance using python 3.

For open and close prices, I use the pandas DataReader functionality.

Can this API be adjusted to read the bid, ask or any other characteristic of the stock?

```
from pandas_datareader import data as web
security = web.DataReader("AAPL", "yahoo", start=startDate, end=endDate)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The Yahoo API it uses only provides daily, trade-based bars. Finer information is usually licensed in a way that a public, free, legal API won't be providing it.